# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Engines\Data.xlsx (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I have an existing file in my system by the name of data but it still says `The system cannot find the file specified.`

I am trying to create an object of an existing class with all the methods to read an xlsx file.

My code:

```
public class sampletestjava {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("learning maven");
    XLS_Reader xls = new XLS_Reader("C:\\Engines\\Data.xlsx");
```

Error

> (java.io.FileNotFoundException): C:\Engines\Data.xlsx 
>           (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: `C:\\Engines\\Data.xlsx` is likely going to need to be `C:\\\\Engines\\Data.xlsx`, as you need to double escape the drive path

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the string of absolute path like the following:

```
  D:/eip_eclipse_workspace/codeTesting/properties/keystore_file/keystore
```

Which, like in your case will be:

```
  XLS_Reader xls = new XLS_Reader("C:/Engines/Data.xlsx");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File myFile = new File("C://Engines/Data.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

OR

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C://Engines/Data.xlsx"));
```

is there any class  or interface like XLS_Reader ?
Even i am also learning but in my knowledge it's not.
plz update me if it is

Work with java.io concept as well
In order to work with Office files you need to understand the "Apache POI."
look for https://www.javatpoint.com/apache-poi-tutorial

Hope this helps!